# Visualizing the process map in Dash using PM4PY

Tags: python, process-mining

I have a Dash app built in which I would like to visualize a simple process map (dfg) using the PM4PY library. Here's a sample code (data can be downloaded from [here](https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de/static/assets/examples/running-example.xes)):

```html
# Import packages
import dash as dash
from dash import Dash, html, dash_table
import pm4py

# Initialize the app
app = Dash(__name__)

# Event log preparation
log = pm4py.read_xes(r'C:\Users\~\running-example.xes')
dataframe = pm4py.format_dataframe(log, case_id='case:concept:name', activity_key='Activity', timestamp_key='time:timestamp')

# DFG preparation
dfg, start_activities, end_activities = pm4py.discover_dfg(dataframe)
p = pm4py.view_dfg(dfg, start_activities, end_activities)

# App layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='My First App with Data'),
    dash_table.DataTable(data=dataframe.to_dict('records'), page_size=10, sort_action='native')
])

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When the application is launched, the process map appears as a separate image:
[image]

In the application, I would like to add a process map below the table. Could anyone help me with this topic? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.